# Where to write JavaScript to Validate updating record in GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using ***GridView1_RowCommand*** event method to Insert, Update record. I want to use JavaScript clientside validation to validate record in update mode. Where can I write JavaScript to make it fire when clicked on the update button?

Comment: is the Update button autogenerated using AutoGenerateEditButton on the GridView?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar (`know-how` of) with the `JavaScript` language, you can write JavaScript in .aspx (markup) or external JavaScript file particularly. If not than use ASP.NET `validation controls`. Note that *to validate user input* you must have to convert GridView fields to "`TemplateFields`".

Comment: Hi AVD, Thanks for your reply. Since all my "Update button" controls are binding while the page is loading, how can I pass JavaScript to this "Update button" control?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `TemplateField`, and put the update button in the `EditItemTemplate`. Assign the correct CommandName to link up to the `RowCommand` event, and use `OnClientClick` to trigger validation.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" OnClientClick="validateData(this);" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```